# Background worker for search and highlight feature

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a simple while loop that allows me to find text within a textbox, but when I am searching for a word that appears several times in the textbox, it locks up the interface for a while. I'd like to move it into a background worker, but I don't think this can be done because the interface elements (i.e. textbox3.text) are on the main thread. How can I make a background worker when the main interface elements are involved?

I found decent information on the web, but I am having trouble implementing other solutions I have read into my particular situation.

```
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Highlight text when search button is clicked
        int index = 0;
        while (index < dragDropRichTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(textBox3.Text))
        {
            dragDropRichTextBox1.Find(textBox3.Text, index, dragDropRichTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            dragDropRichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;
            index = dragDropRichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(textBox3.Text, index) + 1;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you want to do is create sub thread doing the job not to block the UI  thread ( pseudo-code, aka not tested ) :

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Copy text in a non-thread protected string, to be used within the thread sub-routine.
    string searchText = textBox3.Text;
    string contentText = dragDropRichTextBox1.Text;

    // Create thread routine
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => {

        // Iterate through all instances of the string.
        int index = 0;
        while (index < contentText.LastIndexOf(searchText))
        {
            dragDropRichTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {

                // Update control within UI thread
                //Highlight text when search button is clicked
                dragDropRichTextBox1.Find(searchText, index, contentText.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                dragDropRichTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;
            }

            // Go to next instance
            index = contentText.IndexOf(searchText, index) + 1;
        }            
    });
}
```

Again, this is untested, but that would give you the idea.

-- EDIT --

You don't need threading at all, doing all the work between a `dragDropRichTextBox1.SuspendLayout()` and `dragDropRichTextBox1.ResumeLayout()` is enough.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Copy text in a non-thread protected string, to be used within the thread sub-routine.
        string searchText = textBox1.Text;
        string contentText = richTextBox1.Text;

        // Suspend all UI refresh, so time won't be lost after each Find
        richTextBox1.SuspendLayout();

        // Iterate through all instances of the string.
        int index = 0;
        while (index < contentText.LastIndexOf(searchText))
        {
            //Highlight text when search button is clicked
            richTextBox1.Find(searchText, index, contentText.Length, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;

            // Go to next instance
            index = contentText.IndexOf(searchText, index) + 1;
        }

        // Finally, resume UI layout and at once get all selections.
        richTextBox1.ResumeLayout();
    }
```

Comment: I think this could work, except dragDropRichTextBox1 is of the RichTextBox type, which is also part of the main thread too. Would I need to create a new instance of DragDropRichTextBox : RichTextBox to replace dragDropRichTextBox1? If I do that, I'm not sure how I would update the UI. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, maybe replace the richtextbox.invoke() by richtextbox.begininvoke() and that'll remove your blocking ? ( sorry I can't test it atm )

Comment: No need to apologize, anything is appreciated. Correction though, the previous suggestion compiled fine. I missed a line of code originally. Unfortunately it's not giving the desired outcome. Rather than waiting a long time for all the text to highlight at the same time, it's slowly highlighting the search strings one at a time. During this time the interface is still locked up.

Comment: Wait.. Subclassing the control won't change a thing threading wise. What threadpool.QueueUserWorkItem does is create a new thread where you do your computation, and within it, calling the control.invoke() or control.beginInvoke() calls back the ui thread to do some ui stuff with the difference that invoke() is blocking and the other is not

Comment: Something came to my mind, you don't need threading at all actually. All you need is to control.SuspendLayout() before doing all the finds and close it by a control.ResumeLayout(). I'm about to edit my response to give you a better idea.

Comment: @Gernatch, I'm curious,  did the SuspendLayout() / ResumeLayout() made things better for you ?

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use invoke when you're manipulating the UI elements in your background thread

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171728(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: All the actual work here is done by the richtextbox itself, and therefore 99% of the CPU used will be on the UI thread. There's no point just wrapping a thread around an invoke.

Comment: I thought the whole point of his question was how to move that work into a background thread so that the UI doesn't hang while the search function is running. Using a background thread to invoke the UI thread to do all the work is not going to improve the user experience which seems like the goal here.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the Invoke Method on the control.

```
dragDropRichTextBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
  //Your code goes here for whatever you want to do. 
}
```

);

This should fix your problem.

Comment: This won't help at all when he's already running in the main UI thread via the Button Click handler...